# Scala Compilation Error on Vert.x

Tags: scala, vert.x

I'm not a Scala Expert. I just want to run a simple example Verticle on Vert.x.

```
class ScalaServer extends Verticle {
  override def start() {
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, { timerId: Long =>
      vertx.eventBus.publish("news-feed", "News from Scala")
    })
  }
}
```

But when I run this code on Vert.x the compiler complains with the following message:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.Long => org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.EventBus
 required: org.vertx.java.core.Handler[java.lang.Long]
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, { timerId: Long =>
                                            ^
```

Maybe there is someone out there who sees the error right away.

Comment: Are you trying to use scala's SAM synthesis support (java 8 style lambda)? You need to pass `-Xexperimental` to the compiler for that, and you might have to type `timerId` as `java.lang.Long` (bare `Long` means `scala.Long` and is equivalent to java `long`).

Answer (score 1):

> found   : scala.Long => org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.EventBus 
>   required: org.vertx.java.core.Handler[java.lang.Long]

Try follow:

```
class ScalaServer extends Verticle {
  override def start() {
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, new Handler[java.lang.Long]() {
      def handle(timerID: java.lang.Long) = {
        vertx.eventBus.publish("news-feed", "News from Scala")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! This compiles and runs without problems.

Comment: it's terrible need use java types in scala, are you sure than you're importing the vertx libs for scala

import org.vertx.scala.core._
import org.vertx.scala.core.http.HttpServerRequest
import org.vertx.scala.platform.Verticle